# jQuery operation with CSS transition timing issue

Tags: jquery, css, accessibility

I'm trying to create a sidebar animating on the margin property. I'm toggling the `hidden` HTML attribute on the sidebar to make it accessible.

My question is: why does the animation for showing sidebar break after the 1st try? It works on subsequent tries if I add an arbitrary timeout on the `addClass`, but isn't `removeAttr` supposed to be synchronous?

[Run in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gepuxuqugi/edit?html,css,js,output)

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar { 
    margin-left: -200px;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-out;
}

#wrapper.show-aside #sidebar {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

JS

```
// Show sidebar
$('#sidebar').removeAttr('hidden');
$('#wrapper').addClass('show-sidebar');

// Hide sidebar
$('#wrapper').removeClass('show-sidebar');
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#sidebar').attr('hidden', 'hidden');
}, 300); // Wait for CSS transition to finish
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add the `hidden` HTML attribute, it adds `display: none` to the element. CSS transition does not animate the `display` property and so it will create the blunt show/hide effect.

I am not sure if `hidden` attribute is the correct usage for this scenario (please read the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden))

Anyway, if you insist on keeping it then you have to add the setTimeout for adding the class (because it is AFTER the `hidden` attr is removed) and again for removing the attr because it is hidden AFTER the class animation finishes:

```js
$('#show').on("click", function(){
  $('#sidebar').removeAttr('hidden');
  setTimeout(function() { $('#wrapper').addClass('show-sidebar'); },310);
});

$('#hide').on("click", function(){
 $('#wrapper').removeClass('show-sidebar');
  setTimeout(function() { $('#sidebar').attr('hidden', true); },310);
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  left: -100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
}

#wrapper.show-sidebar #sidebar { left: 0; }

#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>

<br/>
<button id="show">Show sidebar</button>
<button id="hide">Hide sidebar</button>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/s9ax6gm5/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I want to show the sidebar animation immediately when the show button is clicked. I understand that the CSS transition does not animate on the `display` property, which is why I'm removing the hidden attribute before adding the class. What I don't understand is why there needs to be a `setTimeout` on adding the class, if those functions are supposed to run synchronously? (There's no callback parameter in `removeAttr`)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't answer my initial question, but a simple workaround would be to wrap the sidebar within another container, and set the `hidden` attribute on the child, so that you aren't hiding/displaying the container, just the contents.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/gulixegoha/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebarWrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">Some content some content some content</div>
  </div>
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

-

```
#sidebarWrapper { 
    margin-left: -200px;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-out;
}

#wrapper.show-aside #sidebarWrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

-

```
$('#show').click(function() {
  $('#sidebar').removeAttr('hidden');
  $('#wrapper').addClass('show-sidebar');
});

$('#hide').click(function() {
  $('#wrapper').removeClass('show-sidebar');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#sidebar').attr('hidden', 'hidden');
  }, 300); // Wait for CSS transition to finish
});
```